# Colspan not getting applied to td using @ViewChild

Tags: angular

I am trying to apply colspan to an td element dynamically and it isnt working. Anbody know the reason why it isnt working.  I cant see the colspan being applied when i inspect the element

Html

```
 <td id = "LegalClassName" class="tableItem" *ngIf="c == 'Legal Class Name'">
                                    {{f.LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel.Description }}</td>
```

Component code

```
@ViewChild('LegalClassName') myLegalClassName: ElementRef;

addSideLetter(id) {
        this.SideLetter[id] = !this.SideLetter[id];
        this.myLegalClassName.nativeElement.setAttribute('colspan', 2);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the template-ref syntax `#LegalClassName` instead of `id="LegalClassName"`. I guess the `this.myLegalClassName` variable is `undefined` in your code?

Anyway, this code looks anti-pattern to me: you could rather use the simplicity of attribute binding instead of retrieving the DOM object yourself (unless your actual logic is more complicated?):

```
<td class="tableItem" *ngIf="c == 'Legal Class Name'" [attr.colspan]="logic_condition ? 2 : 1">
```

Where you properly set the value of `logic_condition` member boolean variable in your component code when it makes sense. That way, you don't care about setting the property yourself (and if you change the value in another place in your component later on, you don't have to update it by hand neither).

Comment: I have created a fiddle and tried and applied your suggestion but unfortunately it doesnt seem to work. https://jsfiddle.net/0xk4hdb5/

Comment: maybe you didn't "save" the jsfiddle, can't see stuff inside (code but nothing shows, and I don't see colspan stuff)

Comment: Sorry. Here you go. https://jsfiddle.net/ranjitmenon/f60bswno/. If you see in the my code I am trying to apply colspan while clicking the AddSideletter button

Comment: You put `colspan` instead of `[colspan]`, fixing that makes the code work. Explanation: when using `colspan`, angular templating engine sets `colspan` attribute to the static string value you give ("logic ? 2: 0"). When using `[colspan]`, templating engine interprets the value as code and evaluates this code each time it is relevant - relying on the change detection mechanism to know when to do that.

Comment: Is the jsiddle that i shared working as it wasnt working for me.

Comment: I just replaced `colspan` with `[colspan]` and it works well in jsfiddle. Do you have a different experience?

Comment: Earlier you told me to  put colspan instead of [colspan]

Comment: can you share your jsfiddle please

Comment: When i use [colspan] , I get error Can't bind to 'colspan' since it isn't a known property of 'td'

Comment: Ah yes my bad, you need to use `[attr.colspan]` because it's an HTML attribute, not an Angular `Input`. (I never said you should use `colspan` instead of `[colspan]`, you misread). Here is the working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0msk4j97/

Comment: The colspan does work not but there is a problem. It is applying to every column. It should apply to only the column that AddSideLetter button is clicked. It shouldnt apply the span for all the columns

Comment: Then just adapt your code accordingly, this is just HTML template from now on. Your Angular question is solved (please make the answer as such to help community if you'd like :) )

Comment: I though the issue is more on the angular end as I would need to apply pro grammatically on the component code on a specific td

Comment: Just use the `[attr.colspan]` on the correct `td`, with proper variables. You have the concept working, just adapt the logic now.

Comment: I actually tried applying logic but not got it yet abs struggling .

Comment: The approach of declaring colspan upfront might not work and we may have to do it dynamically in component code by getting the specific td

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use `id` attribute to access template reference. You should use template reference variable instead:

```
<td #LegalClassName class="tableItem" *ngIf="c == 'Legal Class Name'">    <----- Notice that #LegalClassName is used instead of id="LegalClassName"                             
    {{f.LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel.Description }}
</td>
```

**ALSO** You could use `Renderer2` of Angular to set attribute. To do this, first inject `Renderer2` in your constructor and then use its `setAttribute` method like following:

```
@ViewChild('LegalClassName') myLegalClassName: ElementRef;

constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.renderer.setAttribute(this.myLegalClassName.nativeElement, 'colspan', '2' );
}
```

Here is an explanation of why/when you should use `Renderer2` instead of manipulating the DOM directly

> The Renderer2 class is an abstraction provided by Angular in the form
>   of a service that allows to manipulate elements of your app without
>   having to touch the DOM directly. This is the recommended approach
>   because it then makes it easier to develop apps that can be rendered
>   in environments that don’t have DOM access, like on the server, in a
>   web worker or on native mobile.

Ref: https://alligator.io/angular/using-renderer2/

Hope that helps

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it gave me compilation error saying 2 cant be applied to string. This statement  this.renderer.setAttribute(this.myLegalClassName.nativeElement, 'colspan', 2);

Comment: You can use `'2'` instead of `2` (Please notice single quotes)